# PLS-00103 error while trying to compare numbers

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

Is this prcedure syntaxically wrong? It seems that there is a problem with my if than block. I kepp getting 
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ")" when expecting one of the
     following:
     (

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Verif(TAB VARCHAR2) IS
MAX   NUMBER;
TEMP   NUMBER;
BEGIN
FOR i IN (SELECT * FROM CLIENTS1_1 WHERE NOT REGEXP_LIKE (COL2, (SELECT REGULAREXPR FROM REGULAREXPRES WHERE CATEGORY='ABR'))) LOOP
  MAX:=0;
  FOR j IN (SELECT * FROM ABR) LOOP
  SELECT UTL_MATCH.JARO_WINKLER_SIMILARITY(i.Col2, j.ABR) INTO TEMP FROM DUAL;
  IF (TEMP >= MAX) THEN
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(TEMP);
  end if;
  END LOOP;  
END LOOP;
END;
/
```

I did all the tests. All select queries return real values.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: `MAX` is a reserved keyword, use another word instead.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan Thank you. It worked/

Comment: you're welcome akh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a stupid mistake. Just needed to replace MAX (which is a key word) by another var name.
Thanks to Barbaros Ozhan.